# Shutdown and reboot not working in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

Since I've installed Debian 10 Buster on my laptop (2009 or so ASUS) I'm not able to shutdown or reboot my computer properly. I've re-installed the OS countless times with no success. I'm using LXDE as DE. 
Whenever I press the shutdown or reboot buttom from the GUI or I use the terminal to type the dedicated commands my system hangs for more than twenty minutes on `Reached target Power-Off` or `Reached target Reboot`. 
I've edited the grub configuration file removing the quiet boot option and I've found out the last thing systemd is trying to do is `Stopping disk` when shutting down, or `Synchronizing SCSI cache` when rebooting. 
After reading [this](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#diagnosingshutdownproblems) I tried both `poweroff -f` and `reboot -f` and none of them worked. 
So is this a kernel related issue? I don't know how to proceed. 
I've even saved [my systemd shutdown log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13GEoJhbw9EhhMjZq8f5GjpmuDOhcCjiR) with debug options enabled.

`lscpu |grep -i model` reports:

`Model: 23 Model name: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4400 @ 2.20GHz`

Comment: @matteobin did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @NandanDesai nope, but I'm still working on it. I decided to move the conversation to the [Italian Debian mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-italian/2019/08/msg00114.html) since it seems more active.

Comment: @matteobin oh cool. Please remember to leave a solution here if you find any. It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - I've upgraded my BIOS to fix it.

I had this same exact issue with my older Dell laptop.  I am fairly certain that it has to do with the kernel 4.19 after upgrading from 4.9 when going from Stretch to Buster.  My best guess is that the BIOS (at least mine) have a semi-broken ACPI implementation but the older kernel was able to tolerate it by sending it what it wants to change states.

If you are already on the latest BIOS for your hardware, you may be SOL and either would have to try the latest kernel or downgrade the kernel.  I am no expert in this area and thus perhaps someone with a better understanding can look into the differences between 4.9 and 4.19 in the ACPI power states handling.

I hope this helps at least someone.

Comment: I tried upgrading the BIOS but nothing changed.

Comment: I also upgraded my thinkpad W541 BIOS and still same freezing problem.

Comment: weirdly enough, some times after reboot/shutdown freezing I can ping it while it freezes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing NVIDIA Proprietary Driver following
https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers, kernel and legacy driver **from backports**. That resolved the poweroff issue. The reboot freeze was solved by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=pci"`.

On laptop Asus K70IO (2009, NVIDIA GeForce GT 120M) freshly installed with Debian 10 Buster.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Debian buster an a ACER ASPIRE 3 series laptop and got the same problem. I solved it by updating the linux kernel to the most recent version avaiable from the debian backport repository.

I found this solution on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj1qjFwg_H8.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to summarise the process; as it stands, this is a link-only answer, liable to be deleted.